# Using NetToplogySuite to get the geometry from Geojson file with method (IsWithinDistance) ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, geospatial, geojson

I'm stuck in using NetTopologySuite with geojson file.
I want to get all the points from the geojson and then use the IsWithinDistance() method to get all the points within certain distance. I could deserialize the data and get the coordinates but the method doesn't work. I suppose that the method needs the points to be converted to WKB ? please correct me if I'm mistaken.

I could successfully execute the method when my first source of data stored in database but from json it doesn't work.

---

This is my controller :

```
 public IActionResult GetWeather()
        {


            IList<WeatherViewModel> Tags = new List<WeatherViewModel>();


            var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
            var searchAreaCoordinate = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate(-1.882, 52.486);
            var searchArea = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(searchAreaCoordinate);

            Root weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\local\weatherx.json"));
            var features = (from c in  weather.features select c)
            .Select(x=> new {x.id,x.type,x.geometry.coordinates})
            // .Where(x=>x.Coor.IsWithinDistance(searchArea, 300))
           
            
            .ToList();
            ;

            foreach (var item in features)
            {
                Tags.Add(new WeatherViewModel()
                
                {
                            id = item.id,
                            type = item.type,
                            Long = item.coordinates[0],
                            Lat = item.coordinates[1],
                          
                            WKT = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate( item.coordinates[0] , item.coordinates[1])
                           
                }
                );
            }
            
            return View(Tags);
        }
```

Part of my json class:

```
public class Root
   {
       public string type { get; set; }
       public ParameterDescription parameter_description { get; set; }
       public List<double> bbox { get; set; }
       public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
   }
public class Geometry
   {
       public string type { get; set; }
       public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
   }

   public class Feature
   {
       public string id { get; set; }
       public string type { get; set; }
       public Properties properties { get; set; }
       public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
       public Geometry Coor {get;set;}
   }
```

Here is part of my geojson:

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
  
   "features": [
       {
           "id": "1",
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
               "t": [
                   1,
     
               ],
               "s": [
                   1,
         
               ],
               "Time": [
                   "2021-11-01",

               ]
           },
           "geometry": {
               "type": "Point",
               "coordinates": [
                   -1.881,
                   52.486
               ]
           }
       },
       
   ]
}
```